# from scipy.interpolate import interp1d hangs django

Tags: python, django, scipy

Need to use interp1d from scipy, but if i try to import it, app can't finish loading page.
I have view which works fine:

```
def index(request):
     return render_to_response('price/index.html')
```

As far as i just try to import

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
```

Page loads forever. No errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally could make it work. Need to add directive

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

to apache2 config.